# How to make sqlplus prompt longer than 50 chars?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I've set a prompt in my sqlplus glogin.sql a little bit long, mainly because of some internal variables and control sequence. Starting sqlplus I get the following error:

```
String beginning "truncated_prompt..." is too long. Maximum size is 50 characters.
SQL>
```

...and yes, my prompt is really truncated to 50 characters.

What to do? Is it possible to somehow make this limit higher? (I already tried `SET LONG` and `SET LONGC` without any change.)

(Reacting comment)
I have this long prompt, because I have some control sequences in it, which make it so beautiful. And I am calling it through rlwrapper, which makes the normal keys (page up/down, history search, tab completion, etc) also working, just as in a good command line application.

Comment: It's not possible. Why on earth do you want a prompt so long?

Comment: @Phil I have some control sequences in it, which make my prompt so beautiful. And I am calling it through rlwrapper, which makes the normal keys (page up/down, history search, tab completion, etc) also very userfriendly. But finally, I found a solution. If you gave the downvote, maybe this explanation has the worth of removing/upvoting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer!

The trick is, that the 50 char limit is for the string *before* the variable substitution! The size of the substituted string isn't limited. In my case, shorting `_connect_identifier` to a temporal variable `_ci` was enough:

```
DEFINE _ci=&_connect_identifier
SET SQLPROMPT "(long things)_user'@'_ci'(long things)"
```